# How to Execute a Function after A particular time Like Click a button at 10 am or 11 am?

Tags: python, selenium

I tried these codes.

```
x = 6
        while 1:
            if x < 0.999:
                break
            #execute you function after 6 seconds.
            x -= 0.01
            sleep(0.01)
```

But i need to execute on a particular time . So i tried this:

```
if (self.is_hour_between("09:55:00", "11:20:00")) == True:
            #your function

        else:
            #your function
           
def time_between(self, start, end):
    # Time Now
    now = datetime.now().time()
    # Format the datetime string
    time_format = "%H:%M:%S"
    # Convert the start and end datetime to just time
    start = datetime.strptime(start, time_format).time()
    end = datetime.strptime(end, time_format).time()

    is_between = False
    is_between |= start <= now <= end
    is_between |= end <= start and (start <= now or now <= end)

    return is_between
```

**i wanted to run the function at exactly 10 Am and 11Am .If its not the time then wait for it.else if its the time then go for it without waiting**

Comment: Did you mean to get rid of the `while`?  Also note that a spin loop (repeatedly testing a condition in a tight loop) is incredible inefficient and will eat your battery.  Why not figure out how time is between now and your target time, and sleep for that length of time.

Comment: No i just wanted to run a function a perticular time.Like i wanted to execute a function on 10 AM if its not 10 am then wait for 10 am if its 10 am then directly run that function.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Anwser :

```
import datetime
import time


while True:
    current_dt = datetime.datetime.now()
    time_a = datetime.datetime(current_dt.year, current_dt.month, current_dt.day, 9, 55)
    time_b = datetime.datetime(current_dt.year, current_dt.month, current_dt.day, 11, 20)

    if (time_a<current_dt) and (time_b > current_dt):
        print('ok')
    else:
        time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: Sorry dude you did't get me.My Bad .Ok trying.look i wanted a selenium script to execute at 10 AM because the ticket available for booking is at 10am.So i want my script to wait for 10 am and then click on book now.But the problem is ticket is available twice a day 10am and 11 am.If someone runs the script after 10 am it will not wait for 11 am it will directly click on book now.Thats the problem.

Comment: Ok so you can use my answer and put your click method instead of `print('ok')` OR you can set cron/task scheduler (windows) which execute script on desired time